# CSS Style of round button in sapui5

Tags: button, sapui5

Hi I want to create round corner button in sapui5, separated by vertical boundary. As I am newbie in sapui5, I am not able to find any specific radius property for simple "sap.m.Button". Please suggest some way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom css to achieve this.For this use `class` property in XML.If you are using JSview use `addStyleClass` method.

```
  <Button class="roundClass"
    text="Hello UI5 World"
    press="doSomething" />
```

and in css file use below code. `sapMBtnInner` is standardclass.Do not override the class directly as it will have effect everywhere.(dont use `.sapMBtnInner{}` directly use your custom class before it)

```
.roundClass .sapMBtnInner{
  border-radius:30px;
}
```

And welcome to UI5 world